# Is there a way to easily create release notes with the list of changes (commit) and merge requests on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, devops, git-submodules, changelog

I have a Gitlab project with a repository containing submodules (subrepo). Is there an easy way to generate a release note containing the list of changes and merge requests by bundles that occurred on a certain date over a specific period time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: We support this functionality via Reliza Hub - https://worklifenotes.com/2021/07/23/automated-changelogs-are-now-part-of-reliza-hub/